# Why does existence of formulas for zeroes of $f(x)=0$ where $f \in K[X]$ (degree $2$ or $3$) imply $f$ is solveable by radicals?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Why does existence of formulae for zeroes of $f(x)=0$ where $f \in K[X]$ (degree $2$ or $3$) imply $f$ is solveable by radicals?

It is stated that for quadratic or cubic equations over a field $K$ there exist an extension field $L \supset K$ such that a formulae for zeroes of one of the following polynomials over $K$ exist:

$f_1(x)=ax^2 + bx + c$ and $f_2(x)=ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d \in K[X]$.

Why does the existence of these formulae imply any $f \in K[X]$ of degree $2$ or $3$ is *solveable by radicals* ?

For $f$ to be solveable by radicals there must exist a chain of extension fields of $K$: $L =K_n \supset K_{n-1} \supset \dots \supset K_0 = K$ such that $K_{i} = K_{i-1}(\alpha_i)$ and $a_i^n \in K_{i-1}$ for some $n > 0$ and $f$ splits over $L$ into linear factors.

However, I don't see this chain of extension fields in the case above ?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "formula"?

Comment: formulae, I think.

Answer (score 1):

It works because the formulae you get contain square roots and cube roots, and nothing more complicated.

To take a square root you need an extension of degree $2$ e.g. by a root of $x^2-a=0$.

To take a cube root you need an extension of degree $3$ by a root of $x^3-b=0$. To get all the cube roots you may need a further extension of degree $2$ by a root of $x^2+x+1=0$, which, if you set $y=2x+1$ is an extension by a root of $y^2+3=0$ (if the field does not already contain the cube roots of $1$).

---

Suppose you have $a+\sqrt b$ in the formula, where $a,b \in K_r$ but $\sqrt b \notin K_r$. Extend $K_r$ by a root of $x^2-b=0$ to obtain $K_{r+1}$ - which adds something we can call $\sqrt b$. Then $a+\sqrt b \in K_{r+1}$.

Comment: Yes, I get solutions of the form $k - \sqrt {\text {something}}$ ? Then taking exponents, I don't get rid of the square root.

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen I've added a little explanation of how to deal with that.

Comment: Also how can one ensure square root of an element exists ? Is this by construction of the extension field ?

Comment: How do you know you can find a root of $ x^2 - b = 0$ ?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen You adjoin one so that it belongs to the extension field. In the field $K[x]/\langle x^2-b \rangle$ (with $b$ not a square in $K$) the element $c=x+\langle x^2-b \rangle$ satisfies $c^2=b+\langle x^2-b \rangle$, or in the usual shorthand $c^2=b$. This is the process by which a square root is adjoined to a field.

Comment: Thank you so far @MarkBennet. So the square root is created through isomorphism, I see ? What about a cube root, how is such one created ?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen You use $x^3-b$ to add a cube root of $b$ in a wholly analogous way to the square. Using an irreducible polynomial $p(x)$ in the same way adjoins a root of $p(x)$. You may need to add a cube root of $1$ which is not equal to $1$ - for this $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ and you use $x^2+x+1$ if it is irreducible (if it isn't the roots are already in the field).